# Serious question please help

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sunnah

Salam alikum
I know the waiting time is 4 months for husband and wife. But what about if it’s almost 2 years.

Comment: Unclear question.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with waiting time (in what context). For the rest of us it is unclear what you are referring to? In Islam there's a waiting period ('iddah 
  عدة ) related to a marriage after death or divorce (talaq), but since you didn't specify a context  your question remains unclear

Comment: The question is unclear, as UmH stated. Excuse me if I'm wrong, I guess that you have been married but the marriage has not be *consumed*. I am a westerner and don't know about Islam or Arabic customs, but few centuries ago in the western world, priests would have declared the marriage void (as if never happened).

Comment: @UmH excuse my for misusing a comment, I would like to ask things on Meta. How can I do it, how much reputation points do I need?

Comment: @GyroGearloose You need minimum 5 reputation. The site is https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/